# access attribute of SimpleXMLElement Object

Tags: php, xml, arrays, simplexml

i got this object:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object\n(\n    
[@attributes] => Array\n        (\n            
  [article_number] => 550007\n        )\n\n    
[serial_number] => Array\n        (\n            
   [0] => 5500070000126237\n            
   [1] => 5500070000126246\n            
   [2] => 5500070000126255\n            
   [3] => 5500070000126264\n            
   [4] => 5500070000126273\n        )\n\n)\n
```

I want to access the attribute like this , but it doesn't seem to work:

```
foreach ($product_array as $codes) 
{    
    error_log($codes->product[0]->attributes()->article_number);    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$codes->product[0]['article_number']
```

This should work.

Comment: uhh i fixed it this way: `      foreach($codes->attributes() as $article_number) {
       error_log($article_number);
       //error_log($codes->serial_number);
      }
` gonna accept your answer thought

Comment: +1 Znarkus, only answer I could find to this question surprisingly enough.